# Loop on each row content

Tags: php, android, push-notification

I am having this script to send a push notification to a single user.

I want to make a loop in the script to send the notification to ALL users.

I must get the tokens from the database and loop for each one.

```
<?php

require "init.php";
$message=$_POST['message'];
$title=$_POST['title'];
$path_to_fcm='https://fcm.googleapis.com/fcm/send';
$server_key="MY_SERVER_KEY";
$sql="select * from fcm_info"; //there's one field called fcm_token
$result=mysqli_query($con,$sql);
$row=mysqli_fetch_row($result);
$key=$row[0];

$headers= array(
'Authorization:key='.$server_key,
'Content-Type:application/json'
);

$fields= array('to'=>$key,
'notification'=>array('title'=>$title,'body'=>$message));

$payload=json_encode($fields);

$curl_session= curl_init();
curl_setopt($curl_session,CURLOPT_URL, $path_to_fcm);
curl_setopt($curl_session,CURLOPT_POST, true);
curl_setopt($curl_session,CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, $headers);
curl_setopt($curl_session,CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
curl_setopt($curl_session,CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);
curl_setopt($curl_session,CURLOPT_IPRESOLVE, CURL_IPRESOLVE_V4);
curl_setopt($curl_session,CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $payload);

$result=curl_exec($curl_session);
curl_close($curl_session);
mysqli_close($con);?>
```

What I have tried is:

```
while($d=mysqli_fetch_array($result,MYSQLI_BOTH))
{
echo $d[0]; 
}
```

and I changed:

```
$key to $d[0];
```

But it didn't work,

Any suggestions, please.

//Updated

1. I am getting only one token but I got two in the database
2. MySQLi error

Check it: [Result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YPUYm.png)

//Riggs is this my update:

I used to test your code and no error has shown up.

I added echo $row['fcm_token']; after the while loop but the page is not displaying my echo.

The notification has been sent to the first row of fcm_token in the database. I think Riggs that the loop isn't fetching the second row and it isn't setting the `$key` to the new token.

Can u have a way to simply do:

1. Getting the first-row token value
2. setting the $key to the token
3. Counter ++
4. Getting the second-row token value

//do same steps

Comment: what do you meadn  with "it didn t work"  -- you have error?  show the message .. You have wrong result .? . then show data sample your result and the expected result

Comment: *"But it didn t work"* - Define that; any errors from adding `mysqli_error($con)` to the query? what about error reporting?

Comment: Sorry ,,edited the question
Guys the code worked but it s sending the notification to the only token i get from the database but i Have two,,probably wrong loop ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My guess would be that `fcm_token` is not the first column returned in the query result, when using `SELECT *`

When you query a database using the `*` i.e. return all columns there is no reason why the single column you want will be the first column returned in the result array. So it is dangerous to assume that by using `$row[0]`

Instead specify the column name in the query if you only want specific columns returned, not only do you then know which column will be the first/second/... in the result array, it is also more efficient.

```
$sql="select fcm_token from fcm_info"; //there's one field called fcm_token
$result=mysqli_query($con,$sql);
$row=mysqli_fetch_row($result);
// now using columns positions i.e. $row[0] will be getting the fcm_token col
$key=$row[0];
```

Better still use `mysqli_fetch_assoc()` and the name of the column like

```
$sql="select fcm_token from fcm_info"; //there's one field called fcm_token
$result=mysqli_query($con,$sql);
$row=mysqli_fetch_assoc($result);
$key=$row['fcm_token'];
```

When it comes to your loop over the multiple results returned, again use a column name and use the parameter MYSQLI_ASSOC so the row gets returned as an associative array i.e. the column names are used as the key to the row array.

```
while($row=mysqli_fetch_array($result,MYSQLI_ASSOC))
{
    echo $row['fcm_token]; 
}
```

Or

```
while($row=mysqli_fetch_assoc($result))
{
    echo $row['fcm_token]; 
}
```

RE: You comment, is this what you are suggesting you want to do

```
<?php
require "init.php";
$message=$_POST['message'];
$title=$_POST['title'];
$path_to_fcm='https://fcm.googleapis.com/fcm/send';
$server_key="MY_SERVER_KEY";
$sql="select * from fcm_info"; //there's one field called fcm_token
$result=mysqli_query($con,$sql);

// remove this it is fetching the first row outside the loop
//$row=mysqli_fetch_row($result);
//$key=$row[0];

$headers= array(
                'Authorization:key='.$server_key,
                'Content-Type:application/json'
        );


while($row=mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)) {

    $fields = array('to'=>$row['fcm_token'],
                   'notification'=>array(
                            'title'=>$title,
                            'body'=>$message
                            )
                    );

    $payload = json_encode($fields);

    $curl_session= curl_init();
    curl_setopt($curl_session,CURLOPT_URL, $path_to_fcm);
    curl_setopt($curl_session,CURLOPT_POST, true);
    curl_setopt($curl_session,CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, $headers);
    curl_setopt($curl_session,CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
    curl_setopt($curl_session,CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);
    curl_setopt($curl_session,CURLOPT_IPRESOLVE, CURL_IPRESOLVE_V4);
    curl_setopt($curl_session,CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $payload);

    $result=curl_exec($curl_session);
    curl_close($curl_session);
}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot RiggsFolly but what i want exactly let s suppose i have multiples tokens one is :1234 and other : 5678 and other..
i want to set each token to the $key and send the notification.
but in your example i am still getting one token.
Can t we use for loop ?

Comment: See the edit to the full code. You forgot to remove the fetch after the select, this was fetching the first result and doing nothing with it. Now the loop is processing ALL the results it should work for all results

Comment: Thanks a lot @RiggsFolly i will see it soon